# Launching Python script from zsh and staying in Python shell

Tags: python, shell, zsh

I would like to simplify running Python scripts from within the Python shell. In Python 2, you could just use `execfile(path)`. But in Python 3 it's harder to remember:
`exec(open(path).read())`

So I want a function to run a script, as simple as `run(path)`. I can do this from the Python shell:

```
def run(filename):
    source = open(filename).read()
    code = compile(source, filename, 'exec')
    exec(code)
```

Then I can just type in `run(path)`. This works great, and now I want to simplify things by defining the `run` function every time I launch Python 3.

I'd like to configure my `~/.zshenv` with a zsh alias or function   (say, `py`) that launches Python and tells it to define the `run` function. So that's where I'm stumped. What would a such a zsh command look like? I've tried and failed with things like:

```
py () {
    python -c "\
    def run(filename): \
        source = open(filename).read() \
        code = compile(source, filename, 'exec') \
        exec(code)" \
}
```

But that fails miserably:

```
% py
  File "<string>", line 1
    def run(filename):  source = open(filename).read() code = compile(source, filename, 'exec')  exec(code)
IndentationError: unexpected indent
%
```

And even if it were to work, it would drop back out of the Python shell once the function was defined. Obviously I don't know what I'm doing here. Any pointers?

Also… please don't assume I have asked the right question. Usually on StackOverflow we try to avoid second-guessing posters' assumptions. But go ahead and second-guess mine if there's a better way to get Python to always define a `run` function when it is launched.

Comment: You are not trying to execute a zsh function from inside a Python interactive shell, do you?????

Comment: No, the opposite: I’m trying to define a Python function from zsh.

Comment: This is weird: You can invoke a Python **child process** from Zsh, and you can **stay** in your zsh process and invoke a zsh **function** from there. The concept of calling a function written in Python (or C++,  bash, or whatever) inside your zsh-process is pointless. Perhaps you need to clarify with an example, which effect you want to achieve.

Comment: All I really want is this: every time I launch Python, I want a particular function, `run()`, to be defined. I had the idea that I could do that by creating a zsh command that would define that on Python launch. But I'm totally open to other options. Ideally there would be something like a Profile script that always executes when Python is launched.

Comment: Do you mean "launch an interactive Python shell", or with **every* Python application?

Comment: Have a look at the [Python command line options](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html): With `-m`, you can specify a module which is going to be executed. You can put your definitions inside this module.

Comment: I just stumbled over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68238446/how-to-create-a-suffix-alias-for-files-without-an-extension) post.  I did not know this fancy zsh feature before, but perhaps it would allow you to associate `php` and `php.exe`. Still, a symlink or cover script would probably be the cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this function only for interactive shells, you can write it in a file and then run `python -i file_with_function.py`. The `-i` option will tell the interpreter to drop into an interactive session after whatever is in the `file_with_function.py` file runs.

If you want it for any `.py` file that you will run non-interactively then you can do one of the following:

1. Create a package that contains your run function and install your package on your interpreter. There is a detailed guide on the Python docs (https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/).
2. Add the directory that contains a `.py` file with your function on the PYTHONPATH environmental variable and import it from there.

Comment: I only need it for interactive shells, so your first suggestion works. Sort of. I first tried `echo`ing the string and piping that into the `python -i` command. That didn't work; it dropped me back into zsh. So, figuring I needed to create an actual .py file, I tried     `tmp="/tmp/temp"$RANDOM".py" \
echo "def run(filename): \n\ \
exec(open(filename).read())" > $tmp \
python -i $tmp` ... This almost works—it does execute and stay in the python shell—but for some reason it yields new errors on execution related to namespace and scope, that I don't see when I run directly. Weird.

Comment: I tried your command on my ZSH `tmp="/tmp/temp"$RANDOM".py"; echo "def run(filename): \n exec(open(filename).read())" > $tmp; python -i $tmp` and it worked. I then created a test.py file with a print inside it, and executed it with `run(absolute_path_to_test_py)` and it worked as well, so i cannot see any issues that you might have.

If you haven't found the issue yet, feel free to comment it to see if i can help.

Answer (score 0):

In the command which you are passing to Python (using `python -c`), you start the function definition with a couple of spaces. Spaces at the start of a line are significant in Python. You would get the same error, if you would open a Python shell and write

```
       def foo:
```

with several spaces in front: Python responds with *IndentationError: unexpected indent*.

In addition, your use of backslash characters makes all the linefeeds disappear, with the effect that you are going to define the complete function in a single line. This is also invalid in Python, so even if you would fix the initial spaces, you would still get *SyntaxError: invalid syntax*.

Note that you can use the `-m` option of Python to load initial definition together with starting Python. You can do a

```
python -h
```

to get a list of the valid command line options.